# Class '..\DirectoryList' not found in /home/demoalgacis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php on line 169

Tags: php, magento

While installing Magento-CE-2.1.2 initially blank white screen displayed .Then i added the below code to enable the visibility of the errors.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Now it shows the below error message

```
Class 'Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList' not found in /home/demoalgacis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php on line 169
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove all sub folder from "VAR" folder avilable into magento root,
Then run following command from CLI.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```